# protractor -- Copy the column elements to array , sort it and compare the first array element with the first column data

Tags: arrays, sorting, user-interface, grid, protractor

I am trying to copy a column of UI grid elements to an array and sort it and compare the first element of array with the first column data to check the UI grid column data is sorted correctly.

This is my code --

I get the error - unsorted.then is not a function. Can you please help me. also let me know if i can use any other method.

thanks in advance.

```
    var rows = element(by.id('grid2')).element( by.css('.ui-grid-render-container-body')).all( by.repeater('(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index'));
    var results = [];
       var res =  rows.count().then(function(cnt){                
           console.log('inside loop');
           console.log(cnt);
           for(i=0; i < cnt; i++){
              ele = test.datacell('grid2',i,0);
              ele.getText().then(function(txt){
              console.log(txt);
              results.push(txt);
               });
            }
            var unsorted = results.map(function(element) {
                  console.log(element.getText());
                  return element.getText();
                  });

            var sorted = unsorted.then(function(texts) {
                 return texts.slice(0).sort();
              });

          ele = cmn.datacell('grid1',0,colcount);
           expect(ele.getText()).toEqual(sorted[0]);
```

Comment: I got it working now. can you please let me know how to sort in descending order. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for sorting in descending order you could use try this -

```
var sorted = unsorted.then(function(texts) {
  return texts.slice(0).sort(function (a,b) {
           return b-a;
     });
 });
```

Comment: thanks. i found reverse() is the function to sort in descending order.